# function is not a function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that is supposed to call loadCampaigns() on click but when I click it it says the function is not a function. However if I run loadCampaigns() in the console it runs. It's got to be something simple I'm missing here. Any ideas?

Here is the button code:

`<button id="loadCampaigns" type="button" class="btn pull-left" onclick="loadCampaigns();">Load</button>`

Here is the script:

```
 <script>

    var availableTags = [];
    $( ".auto-complete" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });


    $('#from_username').keydown(function(e){
        if(e.which==13){
            loadCampaigns();
        }else{
            loadUsernameList('#from_username');
        }
    });
    $('#to_username').keydown(function(){
        loadUsernameList('#to_username');
    });



    function loadUsernameList(inputField){
        $.ajax({
            data:{
            username:$(inputField).val()+'%'        
            },url:'/admin/usernameSearch', type: "POST", dataType: "text",
            success:function(data){
                data=$.parseJSON(data);
                if(data.error != undefined){
                    if(data.error !== false){
                        //showError(data.error);
                    }
                    else{
                        $(inputField).autocomplete("option", "source", data.result);
                    }
                }
            } 
        });
    }

    function loadCampaigns(){

        $.ajax({
            data:{
            username:$('#from_username').val()      
            },url:'/admin/loadUserCampaigns', type: "POST", dataType: "text",
            success:function(data){
                data=$.parseJSON(data);
                if(data.error != undefined){
                    if(data.error !== false){
                        //showError(data.error);
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#from_results').html(data.result);
                    }
                }
            } 
        });
    }


</script>
```

Comment: is there an error in the console when you click?

Comment: Is your script tag located before or after the button?

Comment: @isherwood Shouldn't matter. At the time of click all code should be loaded and the function should exist (unless you click really fast).

Comment: Show us the console output.

Comment: OP mentioned the error: `loadCampaign() is not a function`

Comment: What browser are you getting the error?

Comment: No error showing when I click, script is at the very bottom of the page after the button. I'm in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code itself seems to be fine. Here's a small, full working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <button onclick="loadCampaigns();">Load</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function loadCampaigns() {
                alert('hi');
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My advice is to make sure that you're loading the javascript correctly.

I'll also add that it's generally better to register the click event manually rather than using an html `onclick`:

```
$('#loadCampaigns').click(loadCampaigns);
```

If you do that, you can be sure that the loadCampaigns function is defined before you bind the click event to it.

Comment: I took your advice and moved the function into the click function `$('#loadCampaigns').on('click',function(){/*Do Stuff*/});` and it worked.

Comment: I should add that `$('#loadCampaigns').click(loadCampaigns());` didn't work either... not sure why it's not seeing it as a function.

Comment: The issue with `.click(loadCampaigns())` is that `click` takes a callable function. Anonymous functions like your first comment are very common but it should also work to call `.click(loadCampaigns)`, passing the function directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding document ready to your selectors. Does it work?

```js
<script>

    var availableTags = [];

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $( ".auto-complete" ).autocomplete({
          source: availableTags
        });


        $('#from_username').keydown(function(e){
            if(e.which==13){
                loadCampaigns();
            }else{
                loadUsernameList('#from_username');
            }
        });
        $('#to_username').keydown(function(){
            loadUsernameList('#to_username');
        });
    })


    function loadUsernameList(inputField){
        $.ajax({
            data:{
            username:$(inputField).val()+'%'        
            },url:'/admin/usernameSearch', type: "POST", dataType: "text",
            success:function(data){
                data=$.parseJSON(data);
                if(data.error != undefined){
                    if(data.error !== false){
                        //showError(data.error);
                    }
                    else{
                        $(inputField).autocomplete("option", "source", data.result);
                    }
                }
            } 
        });
    }

    function loadCampaigns(){

        $.ajax({
            data:{
            username:$('#from_username').val()      
            },url:'/admin/loadUserCampaigns', type: "POST", dataType: "text",
            success:function(data){
                data=$.parseJSON(data);
                if(data.error != undefined){
                    if(data.error !== false){
                        //showError(data.error);
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#from_results').html(data.result);
                    }
                }
            } 
        });
    }


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

html code

```
 <button id="loadCampaigns" type="button" class="btn pull-left" 
onclick="callLoadCampaigns();">Load</button>
```

js code,

```
<script>
function callLoadCampaigns(){

    $.fn.loadCampaigns();

}
    var availableTags = [];
    $( ".auto-complete" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });


    $('#from_username').keydown(function(e){
        if(e.which==13){
            callLoadCampaigns();
        }else{
            loadUsernameList('#from_username');
        }
    });
    $('#to_username').keydown(function(){
        loadUsernameList('#to_username');
    });



    function loadUsernameList(inputField){
        $.ajax({
            data:{
            username:$(inputField).val()+'%'        
            },url:'/admin/usernameSearch', type: "POST", dataType: "text",
            success:function(data){
                data=$.parseJSON(data);
                if(data.error != undefined){
                    if(data.error !== false){
                        //showError(data.error);
                    }
                    else{
                        $(inputField).autocomplete("option", "source", data.result);
                    }
                }
            } 
        });
    }

    $.fn.loadCampaigns= function(){

        $.ajax({
            data:{
            username:$('#from_username').val()      
            },url:'/admin/loadUserCampaigns', type: "POST", dataType: "text",
            success:function(data){
                data=$.parseJSON(data);
                if(data.error != undefined){
                    if(data.error !== false){
                        //showError(data.error);
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#from_results').html(data.result);
                    }
                }
            } 
        });
    }
</script>
```

Essentially when you call a function for events like onclick, onkeypress etc. as `onclick="clickFunction()"` or `onkeypress="keyPressFunction()"` from your html, you are calling javascript functions which are not jQuery event binders.

You have to use `$.fn.someFunction = function(){/*some code*/}` then you can do a `$("#someElement").someFunction()`.

In my answer I call a `callLoadCampaigns()` on click event, bind it to `loadCampaigns()` by calling `$.fn.loadCampaigns();` which is more maintainable and structured.